# How to make a graphic using numbers with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to break a number in a table field and turn it into an array.

input_table

```
  +------+---------+
  | id   | number  |
  +------+---------+
  |  1   |   7     |
  |  2   |   8     |
  +------+---------+
```

for the id 1 (which has 7 number) the output what I need in php is:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
   2 3 4 5 6 
     3 4 5 
       4
```

How to do this?

```
  for ($q=1; $q <= $obj->number  ; $q++) { 
         echo "$q";
        //This only turn 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
  }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site to do your homework assignments for you...

Comment: Lol how do you know that it is a homework. I am just wondering how to do this. I am just improving my skills.

Comment: Could you post the code that you have so far? What problem are you having?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried thus far, and how you intend to handle even numbers (like the 8 in your question).

Comment: Only the master of php who can answer this question. :)

Comment: Regarding the 'homework' policy of this site: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Obviously the "work done so far" here consists in barely nothing

Comment: @alisa "I edit the question with the code I have so far" - is this a joke?

Comment: I appreciate people who give the idea on how to do this instead only comment nothing. :)

Comment: *"Turn interger into an array"* - Question title should have read as *"How to make a graphic using numbers with PHP"*.

Comment: You're welcome Alisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this.

```
$set = array( 7, 8 );
echo '<pre>';
foreach( $set as $number ){
  //assuming number is your INT
  $array = range( 1, $number );
   while( count( $array ) ){
       echo "\n";
       var_export( $array );
       //remove first element
       array_shift( $array );
       //remove last element
       array_pop($array);
   }
}
```

Outputs:
For 7

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
)
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 6,
)
array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5,
)
array (
  0 => 4,
)
```

For 8

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
  7 => 8,
)
array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 5,
  4 => 6,
  5 => 7,
)
array (
  0 => 3,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5,
  3 => 6,
)
array (
  0 => 4,
  1 => 5,
)
```

I'll leave it to you to build a multi-dimensional array out of that.

If you just want the output, than use `echo implode(' ', $array );` in place of `var_export()`.  Such as this:

```
$set = array( 7, 8 );
echo '<div style="text-align:center">';
foreach( $set as $number ){
      //assuming number is your INT
      $array = range( 1, $number );
       while( count( $array ) ){
           echo implode(' ', $array );
           //remove first element
           array_shift($array);
           //remove last element
           array_pop($array); 
           echo '<br>';
       }
       echo '<br>';
 }
 echo '</div>';
```

Outputs:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   2 3 4 5 6
     3 4 5
       4

 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
   2 3 4 5 6 7
     3 4 5 6
       4 5
```

Comment: wow, very long answer. Thanks +1 because it improves my skills. :)

Comment: It's not long at all?  The output is long, but that is only so it's easy to read.  Takes only like 5 lines of 'real' code.

Comment: thanks for the idea of PHP Range() :)

Comment: Sure, using Range() saves you a loop.

Comment: Wow, it's so complete with the edited version. Thank you very much PHP master! :*

Comment: Sure thing, just make sure you leaned something from the examples.  Even if it's just to use a few functions such as range, and implode.  PHP has great array support, don't be afraid to explore it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

 $n = 7; //or whatever you want
 echo '<div style="text-align:center">';
 for($i=0;$i<=round($n/2,0);$i++){
   for($j=$i; $j<$n-$i;$j++){
      echo ($j+1).' ';
   }
   echo "<br />\n";
 }
 echo '</div>';
```

Comment: thanks +1. It improves my skills. Thanks!

Comment: I would say to use a bit more verbose variables, all the $i, $n, $j etc... can get hard to read.

Comment: I would say you can't be serious.

Comment: Why not? You also leave a ' ' empty space at the end of each row ( but who's worried about that ).  Surly just schematics, lol.  Anyway, this is a bottom up answer, where mine is a top down answer.  Either should do the job.

Comment: I think in this kind of question there should be an answer as schematic as possible. This is a algorithm lesson not the recipe.